# what should i do to get array like this in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have one array as below :

```
Array
(
 [Sep] => Array
    (
        [Support Help Desk] => 24.67
        [Development] => 7.74
        [Consulting Services] => 4.04
    )

[Oct] => Array
    (
        [Support Help Desk] => 14.38
        [Business Activity] => 1.92
        [Maintenance Tasks] => 1.00
        [Development] => 2.11
    )

)
```

and i want array like this :

```
   Array
    (
        [Support Help Desk] => 24.67,14.38
        [Development] => 7.74,2.11           
        [Consulting Services] => 4.04,0
        [Business Activity] => 0,1.92
        [Maintenance Tasks] => 0,1.00
    )
```

I am using php with zend framework.
But i don't know what method should i use to get array like this ?

can anyone please guide me ?

-

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third time lucky! I missed out on some subtleties in the question originally. Try the following code - it's a bit loopy but it should work for you.

I am assuming that your original array is called `$data`.

```
// first we need to 'normalise' or fill in the blanks in the contents of the sub array
// get a unique list of all the keys shared - doing it manually here

$keys = ['Support Help Desk', 'Business Activity', 'Maintenance Tasks', 'Development', 'Consulting Services'];

// create a default array with $keys, assigning 0 as the value of each

$default = array_fill_keys($keys, 0);

// next fill in the blanks...
// get the diff (missing keys) between the current element and the default array
// merge the missing key/value pairs

array_walk($data, function(&$month, $key, $default) {
    $diff = array_diff_key($default, $month);
    $month = array_merge($diff, $month);
}, $default);


// now the array is normalised
// flatten the array... where there are duplicate values for a key, and
// there will be in all cases now including default values
// a sub array is created

$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $data);

// finally loop over the merged array
// and implode each array of values into a comma separated list

foreach ($merged as &$element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        $element = implode(', ', $element);
    }
}

// done :)

var_dump($merged);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=5)
  'Business Activity' => string '0, 1.92' (length=7)
  'Maintenance Tasks' => string '0, 1' (length=4)
  'Support Help Desk' => string '24.67, 14.38' (length=12)
  'Development' => string '7.74, 2.11' (length=10)
  'Consulting Services' => &string '4.04, 0' (length=7)
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

[Live example at eval.in](https://eval.in/134701)

Comment: Thanks Darragh.. It works. I am getting keys separately and than using your method. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is stored in `$main_arr` and result array is `$result_arr`.

```
$result_arr = array();

foreach ($main_arr as $month) {
    foreach ($month as $key => $val) {
        if (!isset($result_arr[$key])) {
            $result_arr[$key] = array($val);
        } else {
            array_push($result_arr[$key], $val);
        }
    } 
}

foreach ($result_arr as $key => $val) {
    $result_arr[$key] = implode(', ',  $val);
}

print_r($result_arr); //Final output.
```